# What does Python's "==" really do

Tags: python

I was working on optimizing the run-time of a program and got to wondering what "==" in Python really does behind the scenes. In particular, I noticed that it can check whether two large "similar" objects are the same really fast. For instance, if you have two strings of length 10 million and they only differ by a character, running == on them takes about as much time as running 2 == 3.

Comment: The thing is that strings are immutable in  python, so it probably checks ids of strings like this str1 == str2 is same as id(str1) == id(str2), which do not depend on string length

Comment: @batiskaf Immutable objects with the same values need not have the same `id`. That is, `s1 = "this is a test"; s2 = "this is a test"; id(s1) == id(s2)` can return `False` (in fact, it does on my machine).

Comment: Do they differ in the first character or the last character?

Answer (score 6):

`==` delegates to the left-hand-side's object's `__eq__` special method, if there.  And string objects definitely have one, and it's highly optimized.  So that's really all there is to it...

Comment: Got ya. I thought of this but thought it was unlikely since I timed both the cases mentioned above with time.time() and got the same result. There actually was a difference though, it was just really small. I tested them again, this time repeating the == operation a hundred million times, and got a discrepancy of 2.07 seconds. I'm still curious about what the string alg. is though seeing as it's almost as fast in comparing strings of length 10^7 as the int alg. is in comparing 2 and 3!

Comment: Look in `Py-2.7.9/Objects/stringobject.c` at line 1192 and following (after downloading and unpacking the source code, of course:-), and you'll see the magic's all in today C compilers and CPU hardware -- it's just `memcmp`, after comparing string lengths and first characters for possible fast-fails.